# How to go to a folder in Terminal

Tags: command-line

I'm new to Ubuntu and I need to know how I go to a folder on my desktop in Terminal. I also need to extract a file from the folder if you could tell me where to put the command to extract it as well. Thanks

Comment: You need to ask another question about that "extract" command. However, before you do, please search this website for previous answers. Take a look at this search: http://askubuntu.com/search?tab=relevance&q=how%20do%20I%20extract

Answer (score 4):

Open terminal then type the below command:

```
cd ~/Desktop/[Name of the folder]
pwd
```

This should show the preset working directory which should be `/home/[username]/Desktop/[Name of the folder]`.

Comment: When I enter cd~/Desktop/Name it says that the folder can not be found.

Comment: @Agameg That's because you don't have any directory named `Name` in `~/Desktop`

Comment: I should have told [Name of the folder] should be replaced with the actual folder name... My bad...

Comment: I knew to replace "name" with the name of the folder.